# Convert tables to presence/absence matrix python

Tags: python

From two tabular files:

file1.txt

```
name1  house1
name2  house1
name3  house1
name4  house2
name5  house2
name6  house2
```

and file2.txt

```
name1  car
name2  bike
name3  skate
name4  car
name5  motorcycle
name6  boat
```

I want to use the information from both dictionaries to create a presence/absence matrix like this.

```
       car  motorcycle  bike  boat  skate
house1  1       0         1     0     1
house2  1       1         0     1     0
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    col_names = ['name', 'house']
    df1 = pd.read_csv(file1, sep='\t', header=None, names=col_names)

with open('file2.txt', 'r') as file2:
    col_names = ['name', 'transport']
    df2 = pd.read_csv(file2, sep='\t', header=None, names=col_names)

    # include the values from df1 into the df2 creating a new column        
    df2['house'] = df2['name'].map(df1.set_index('name')['house'])

    g = df2.groupby('house')['transport'].apply(list).reset_index()


    g.join(pd.get_dummies(g['transport'].apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0)).drop('transport', 1)

    print g
```

Doing this, I obtained this output:

```
    house                transport
0  house1       [car, bike, skate]
1  house2  [car, motorcycle, boat]
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it yourself first? Stepping through the code & examining values should help...

Comment: any suggestion about where to start debugging?

Comment: The technique is always the same: https://github.com/matthew-brett/multibuild/pull/131#issuecomment-364652410

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way.

**Setup**

```
# df1
  individual   house
0      name1  house1
1      name2  house1
2      name3  house1
3      name4  house2
4      name5  house2
5      name6  house2

# df2
  individual   transport
0      name1         car
1      name2        bike
2      name3       skate
3      name4         car
4      name5  motorcycle
5      name6        boat
```

**Solution**

```
df2['house'] = df2['individual'].map(df1.set_index('individual')['house'])
g = df2.groupby('house')['transport'].apply(list).reset_index()

g.join(pd.get_dummies(g['transport']\
 .apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0)).drop('transport', 1)
```

**Result**

```
    house  bike  boat  car  motorcycle  skate
0  house1     1     0    1           0      1
1  house2     0     1    1           1      0
```

**Explanation**

There are 3 steps:

1. Add 'house' column to `df2`, mapped from `df1`.
2. Group transports by house.
3. Use `pd.get_dummies` to expand `transports` column to dummy columns.

Comment: I just became confused about the position to include these lines. Do I have to include it between: 
"df = pd.read_csv(infile, sep='\t', header=None, names=col_names)
 [INCLUDENEW LINES HERE] 
#create an empty dataframe to hold the presence/absence
paMatrix 
??

Comment: It seems so. You need to have defined 2 dataframes beforehand, `df1 = pd.read_csv(...)` and `df2 = pd.read_csv(...)`.

Comment: I set up both df using the files as input files and nothing. I will re-write the question including your suggestions and the new script. Could you help me?

Comment: Don't worry, I  realized that your g.join(...) needs to be printed or used as a variable. I decided to print, now I need to remove the rowames column (0, 1)