# dictionary to dataframe presence/absence

Tags: python, pandas

From a 2D dictionary, how to convert it into a dataframe or matrix of presence/absence where the values, in the lists) are the columns and keys are the row names?
Accumulating the values in a list, I goal is to organize them in a matrix.

I had been trying this but no success:

```
values = set()

for genome, info in dict_cluster.items():
    for v in info:
        #t = [genome, ([v for v in info])]
        t = [genome,v]
    print pd.DataFrame(t)
```

Input:

```
A ['arylpolyene', 'hserlactone', 'hserlactone', 'nrps', 'siderophore', 't1pks-nrps', 'terpene', 'thiopeptide', 'transatpks-nrps']
B ['hserlactone', 'hserlactone-arylpolyene', 'nrps', 'siderophore', 'thiopeptide']
C ['nrps', 'nrps', 'nrps', 'siderophore', 't1pks-nrps', 't1pks-nrps']
D ['nrps', 'siderophore', 't1pks-nrps']
```

Output:

```
    arylpolyene siderophore hserlactone-arylpolyene transatpks-nrps terpene thiopeptide hserlactone nrps    t1pks-nrps
A   1   2   0   1   1   1   2   1   1
B   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0
C   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   3   2
D   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
```

And my output is this:

```
                 0
0  GCF_900068895.1
1  transatpks-nrps
                 0
0  GCA_002415165.1
1      thiopeptide
                 0
0  GCA_000367685.2
1       t1pks-nrps
                 0
0  GCA_002732135.1
1       t1pks-nrps
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert tables to presence/absence matrix python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49035358/convert-tables-to-presence-absence-matrix-python)

Comment: maybe not so duplicated because in this case there is one unique dictionary and the question is how to organize all values in a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with `dictionary comprehension` and assign to `DataFrame`:

```
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame({k:Counter(v) for k, v in d.items()}).T.fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)

   arylpolyene  hserlactone  hserlactone-arylpolyene  nrps  siderophore  \
A            1            2                        0     1            1   
B            0            1                        1     1            1   
C            0            0                        0     3            1   
D            0            0                        0     1            1   

   t1pks-nrps  terpene  thiopeptide  transatpks-nrps  
A           1        1            1                1  
B           0        0            1                0  
C           2        0            0                0  
D           1        0            0                0
```

EDIT:

For indicator values use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html):

```
d = {'A': ['arylpolyene', 'hserlactone', 'hserlactone', 'nrps', 'siderophore', 't1pks-nrps', 'terpene', 'thiopeptide', 'transatpks-nrps'],
'B': ['hserlactone', 'hserlactone-arylpolyene', 'nrps', 'siderophore', 'thiopeptide'],
'C' :['nrps', 'nrps', 'nrps', 'siderophore', 't1pks-nrps', 't1pks-nrps'],
'D': ['nrps', 'siderophore', 't1pks-nrps']}
```

---

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(d.values()),columns=mlb.classes_, index=d.keys())
print (df)
   arylpolyene  hserlactone  hserlactone-arylpolyene  nrps  siderophore  \
A            1            1                        0     1            1   
B            0            1                        1     1            1   
C            0            0                        0     1            1   
D            0            0                        0     1            1   

   t1pks-nrps  terpene  thiopeptide  transatpks-nrps  
A           1        1            1                1  
B           0        0            1                0  
C           1        0            0                0  
D           1        0            0                0
```

Comment: It is not printing the values over 1 when the lists in values contain repetitive elements

Comment: should you include both answers? Indeed, both are very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
val = {'A': ['arylpolyene', 'hserlactone', 'hserlactone', 'nrps', 'siderophore', 't1pks-nrps', 'terpene', 'thiopeptide', 'transatpks-nrps'],
       'B': ['hserlactone', 'hserlactone-arylpolyene', 'nrps', 'siderophore', 'thiopeptide'],
       'C': ['nrps', 'nrps', 'nrps', 'siderophore', 't1pks-nrps', 't1pks-nrps'],
       'D': ['nrps', 'siderophore', 't1pks-nrps']}
all_val = []
for k in val:
    for v in val[k]:
        all_val.append((k,v))

df = pd.DataFrame(all_val,columns=['key','val']).set_index('key')
df_count = df.pivot_table(index='key',columns='val',aggfunc=len)
```

Output:

```
val  arylpolyene  hserlactone  hserlactone-arylpolyene  nrps  siderophore  \
key                                                                         
A            1.0          2.0                      NaN   1.0          1.0   
B            NaN          1.0                      1.0   1.0          1.0   
C            NaN          NaN                      NaN   3.0          1.0   
D            NaN          NaN                      NaN   1.0          1.0   

val  t1pks-nrps  terpene  thiopeptide  transatpks-nrps  
key                                                     
A           1.0      1.0          1.0              1.0  
B           NaN      NaN          1.0              NaN  
C           2.0      NaN          NaN              NaN  
D           1.0      NaN          NaN              NaN
```

Comment: Without 'NaN', yes

Answer (score 0):

This should do your work (I'm using Python3):

```
my_dict = {
            'A': ['arylpolyene', 'hserlactone', 'hserlactone', 'nrps', 'siderophore', 't1pks-nrps', 'terpene', 'thiopeptide', 'transatpks-nrps'],
            'B': ['hserlactone', 'hserlactone-arylpolyene', 'nrps', 'siderophore', 'thiopeptide'],
            'C': ['nrps', 'nrps', 'nrps', 'siderophore', 't1pks-nrps', 't1pks-nrps'],
            'D': ['nrps', 'siderophore', 't1pks-nrps']
            }

rows_list=list(my_dict.keys())
values=list(my_dict.values())
rows_size=len(rows_list)

columns_list = []

for sublist in values:
    for item in sublist:
        if item not in columns_list:
            columns_list.append(item)

columns_size = len(columns_list)

#initialize adjacent matrix
print('Initial adjacent matrix')
adjacent = [ [0]*columns_size for i in range(rows_size) ]
for row in adjacent:
    print(row)

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    for v in value:
        adjacent[rows_list.index(key)][columns_list.index(v)] += 1

print('-'*50)
print('Final adjacent matrix')
for row in adjacent:
    print(row)
```

In the first loop `for sublist in values:` I create a list with the values you want as columns without duplicates.

In `adjacent = [ [0]*columns_size for i in range(rows_size) ]` I create a list with as many elements as the number of your dictionary keys. Each of these elements is a list with as many elements as the number of your column values.

I tried to do it as much simple as possible, tell me if there is something you can't figure out :)